# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__ while trying to export a dictionary to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, oop, export-to-csv

I have seen this YouTube tutorial for a Python expense tracker and trying to add more functionality by allowing you to import or export data to a CSV. I keep facing errors. I also tried to make a function for writing to CSV using a dictionary but faced more problems.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction , QPainter
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHeaderView, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
                               QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QWidget)
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChartView, QPieSeries, QChart




class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.items = 0
        #Dummy Data
        self._data = {"Water": [24], 
                      "Rent": [1000], 
                      "Coffee": [30],
                      "Grocery": [300], 
                      "Phone": [45], 
                      "Internet": [70]}
        with open("aib_october.csv", 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames=self._data)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(self._data)
        # Left Widget
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Description", "Price"])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        # Chart
        self.chart_view = QChartView()
        self.chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Right Widget
        self.description = QLineEdit()
        self.price = QLineEdit()
        self.add = QPushButton("Add")
        self.clear = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.quit = QPushButton("Quit")
        self.plot = QPushButton("Plot")
        self.export = QPushButton("export")

        # Disabling 'Add' button
        self.add.setEnabled(False)

        self.right = QVBoxLayout()
        self.right.addWidget(QLabel("Description"))
        self.right.addWidget(self.description)
        self.right.addWidget(QLabel("Price"))
        self.right.addWidget(self.price)
        self.right.addWidget(self.add)
        self.right.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.right.addWidget(self.chart_view)
        self.right.addWidget(self.export)
        self.right.addWidget(self.clear)
        self.right.addWidget(self.quit)

        # QWidget Layout
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        #self.table_view.setSizePolicy(size)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.right)

        # Set the layout to the QWidget
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Signals and Slots
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.add_element)
        self.quit.clicked.connect(self.quit_application)
        self.plot.clicked.connect(self.plot_data)
        self.clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_table)
        self.export.clicked.connect(self.clear_table)
        self.description.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
        self.price.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)

        # Fill example data
        self.fill_table()

    @Slot()
    def add_element(self):
        des = self.description.text()
        price = self.price.text()

        try:
            price_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"{float(price):.2f}")
            price_item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

            self.table.insertRow(self.items)
            description_item = QTableWidgetItem(des)

            self.table.setItem(self.items, 0, description_item)
            self.table.setItem(self.items, 1, price_item)

            self.description.setText("")
            self.price.setText("")

            self.items += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not an invalid input:", price, "Make sure to enter a price!")


    @Slot()
    def check_disable(self, x):
        if not self.description.text() or not self.price.text():
            self.add.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.add.setEnabled(True)

    @Slot()
    def plot_data(self):
        # Get table information
        series = QPieSeries()
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            text = self.table.item(i, 0).text()
            number = float(self.table.item(i, 1).text())
            series.append(text, number)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.chart_view.setChart(chart)

    @Slot()
    def quit_application(self):
        QApplication.quit()

    def fill_table(self, data=None):
        data = self._data if not data else data
        for desc, price in data.items():
            description_item = QTableWidgetItem(desc)
            price_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"{price:.2f}")
            price_item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
            self.table.insertRow(self.items)
            self.table.setItem(self.items, 0, description_item)
            self.table.setItem(self.items, 1, price_item)
            self.items += 1

    @Slot()
    def clear_table(self):
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.items = 0


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("The pynancial advisor")

        # Menu
        self.menu = self.menuBar()
        self.file_menu = self.menu.addMenu("File")

        # Exit QAction
        exit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.exit_app)

        self.file_menu.addAction(exit_action)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    @Slot()
    def exit_app(self, checked):
        QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # QWidget
    widget = Widget()
    # QMainWindow using QWidget as central widget
    window = MainWindow(widget)
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()

    # Execute application
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what do "I keep facing errors" and "I faced more problems" mean? Please [edit] the full errors, with traceback, into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line.

```
price_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"{price:.2f}")
```

The error says 'unsupported format string passed'. Removing the :.2f seems to fix it. I'm not sure why QTableWidgetItem seems unable to handle this, but using .format works and defaults to two decimal places.

```
price_item = QTableWidgetItem("{}".format(price))
```